# Make list dynamic from static list in php

Tags: php, html

I am converting a static html site to dynamic in php, I have a `<ol>` where `<li>` are added statically i.e user testimonials, when added a new testimonials i need the list to increment automatically. i.e if one testimonials the bullet should be, for 2 the bullets are 2 and so on. My html code is:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators new">
    <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

`#quote-carousel` is the id for a testimonial slide

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">
            <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <?php 

                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'testimonials_post'                  
                        );
                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                            $i = 1;     
                            $bullets="";        
                            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                                $the_query->the_post();
                                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                                $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);
                                $post_content = get_the_content($post_id);
                                $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'medium');
                ?>
                    <div class="item <?php echo $the_query->current_post >= 1 ? '' : 'active'; ?> text-center">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <img src="<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>" class="img-o">
                                <?php echo $post_content; ?>
                                <small><strong><?php echo $post_title; ?></strong></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $activeclass="";
                    if($i==1){
                        $activeclass='class="active"';
                    }
                    $bullets.='<li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="'.($i-1).'" '.$activeclass.'></li>';
                    $i++;
                        }


                        }

                        wp_reset_query();

                    ?>
                </div>
                <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators new">
                    <?php
                    echo $bullets;
                    ?>

                </ol>
            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome. What is your question? Can we see the code you already have?

Comment: @SadaKhan Don't post your code in the comments, add it as an edit to your question!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">
            <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <?php 

                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'testimonials_post'                  
                        );
                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                            $i = 1;     
                            $bullets="";        
                            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                                $the_query->the_post();
                                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                                $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);
                                $post_content = get_the_content($post_id);
                                $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'medium');
                ?>
                    <div class="item <?php echo $the_query->current_post >= 1 ? '' : 'active'; ?> text-center">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <img src="<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>" class="img-o">
                                <?php echo $post_content; ?>
                                <small><strong><?php echo $post_title; ?></strong></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $activeclass="";
                    if($i==1){
                        $activeclass='class="active"';
                    }
                    $bullets.='<li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="'.($i-1).'" '.$activeclass.'></li>';
                    $i++;
                        }


                        }

                        wp_reset_query();

                    ?>
                </div>
                <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators new">
                    <?php
                    echo $bullets;
                    ?>

                </ol>
            </div>
```

Comment: The list is now dynamic.

Comment: I have edited your post with the code. This is not an answer to your question.